# How to program a delay in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga, morse-code

I'm trying to make a morse code display using an led. I need a half second pulse of the light to represent a dot and a 1.5 second pulse to represent a dash.

I'm really stuck here. I have made a counter using an internal 50MHz clock on my FPGA. The machine I have to make will take as input a 3 bit number and translate that to a morse letter, A-H with A being 000, B being 001 and so on. I just need to figure out how to tell the FPGA to keep the led on for the specified time and then turn off for about a second (that would be the delay between a dot pulse and a dash pulse).

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.
Also, it has to be synthesizable.

Here is my code. It's not functioning yet. The error message it keeps giving me is:

> Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "c3[0]"
>   at part4.v(149)

```
module part4 (SELECT, CLK, CLOCK_50, RESET, led);
input [2:0]SELECT;
input RESET, CLK, CLOCK_50;
output reg led=0;
reg [26:0] COUNT=0; //register that keeps track of count
reg [1:0] COUNT2=0; //keeps track of half seconds
reg halfsecflag=0;  //goes high every time half second passes
reg dashflag=0;     //goes high every time 1 and half second passes
reg [3:0] code;     //1 is dot and 0 is dash. There are 4 total
reg [1:0] c3;       //keeps track of the index we are on in the code.
reg [3:0] STATE;    //register to keep track of states in the state machine
reg done=0;         //a flag that goes up when one morse pulse is done.
reg ending=0;       //another flag that goes up when a whole morse letter has flashed
reg [1:0] length;   //This is the length of the morse letter. It varies from 1 to 4
wire i;             // if i is 1, then the state machine goes to "dot". if 0 "dash"

assign i = code[c3];

parameter START= 4'b000, DOT= 4'b001, DASH= 4'b010, DELAY= 4'b011, IDLE= 
4'b100;

parameter A= 3'b000, B=3'b001, C=3'b010, D=3'b011, E=3'b100, F=3'b101, 
G=3'b110, H=3'b111;


always @(posedge CLOCK_50 or posedge RESET) //making counter
begin
    if (RESET == 1)
        COUNT <= 0;
    else if (COUNT==8'd25000000)
    begin
        COUNT <= 0;
        halfsecflag <= 1;
    end
    else
    begin
        COUNT <= COUNT+1;
        halfsecflag <=0;
    end
end

always @(posedge CLOCK_50 or posedge RESET)
begin
    if (RESET == 1)
        COUNT2 <= 0;
    else if ((COUNT2==2)&&(halfsecflag==1))
    begin
        COUNT2 = 0;
        dashflag=1;
    end
    else if (halfsecflag==1)
        COUNT2= COUNT2+1;
end



always @(RESET) //asynchronous reset
begin
    STATE=IDLE;
end


always@(STATE) //State machine
begin
    done=0;
    case(STATE)

        START: begin
            led = 1;
            if (i) STATE = DOT;
            else STATE = DASH;
        end

        DOT: begin
            if (halfsecflag && ~ending) STATE = DELAY;
            else if (ending) STATE= IDLE;
            else STATE=DOT;
        end

        DASH: begin
            if ((dashflag)&& (~ending))
                STATE = DELAY;
            else if (ending)
                STATE = IDLE;
            else STATE = DASH;
        end

        DELAY: begin
            led = 0;
            if ((halfsecflag)&&(ending))
                STATE=IDLE;
            else if ((halfsecflag)&&(~ending))
            begin
                done=1;
                STATE=START;
            end
            else STATE = DELAY;
        end

        IDLE: begin
            c3=0;
            if (CLK) STATE=START;
            else STATE=IDLE;
        end

        default: STATE = IDLE;

    endcase
end


always @(posedge CLK)
begin
    case (SELECT)
        A: length=2'b01;
        B: length=2'b11;
        C: length=2'b11;
        D: length=2'b10;
        E: length=2'b00;
        F: length=2'b11;
        G: length=2'b10;
        H: length=2'b11;
        default: length=2'bxx;
    endcase
end

always @(posedge CLK)
begin
    case (SELECT)
        A: code= 4'b0001;
        B: code= 4'b1110;
        C: code= 4'b1010;
        D: code= 4'b0110;
        E: code= 4'b0001;
        F: code= 4'b1011;
        G: code= 4'b0100;
        H: code= 4'b1111;
        default: code=4'bxxxx;
    endcase
end

always @(posedge CLK)
begin 
    if (c3==length) 
    begin
        c3<=0; ending=1;
    end
    else if (done)
        c3<= c3+1;
    end 
endmodule
```

Comment: Start with making a counter which generates a high signal for one clock cycle every 0.5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay a year later, I know exactly what one should do if they want to create a delay in their verilog program! Essentially, what you should do is create a timer using one of the clocks on your FPGA. For me on my Altera DE1-SoC, the timer I could use is the 50MHz clock known as CLOCK_50. What you do is make a timer module that triggers on the positive (or negative, doesn't matter) edge of the 50MHz clock. Set up a count register that holds a constant value. For example, reg [24:0] timer_limit = 25'd25000000; This is a register that can hold 25 bits. I've set this register to hold the number 25 million. The idea is to flip a bit every time the value in this register is exceeded. Here's some pseudocode to help you understand:

```
    //Your variable declarations
    reg [24:0] timer_limit = 25'd25000000; //defining our timer limit register
    reg [25:0] timer_count = 0; //See note A
    reg half_sec_clock;

    always@(posedge of CLOCK_50) begin
    if timer_count >= timer_limit then begin
       reset timer_count to 0;
       half_sec_clock = ~half_sec_clock; //toggle your half_sec_clock
    end
```

Note A: Setting it to zero may or may not initialize count, it's always best to include a reset function that clears your count to zero because you don't know what the initial state is when you're dealing with hardware.

This is the basic idea of how to introduce timing into your hardware. You need to use an onboard clock on your device, trigger on the edge of that clock and create your own slower clock to measure things like seconds. The example above will give you a clock that triggers periodically every half second. For me, this allowed me to easily make a morse code light that could flash on either 1 half second count, or 3 half seconds. My best advice to you beginners is to work in a modular fashion. For example build your half second clock and then test it out to see if you can get a light on your FPGA to toggle once every half second (or whatever interval you want). :) I really hope this is the answer that helps you. I know this is what I was looking for when I originally posted this question so long ago.

Answer (score 4):

I have been reading your code and there are many issues:

1. The code is not formatted.
2. You did not provide a test-bench. Did you write one?
3. *"Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net"* Search on stack exchange for the error message. It has been asked many times.
4. Use always @(*) not e.g. always @(STATE) you are missing signals like `i, halfsecflag, ending`. But see point 6: You want the STATE in a clocked section.
5. Where you use always @(posedge CLK) you must use non-blocking assignments: `<=`.
6. There are many places where you use `always @(posedge CLK)` where you want to use `always @(*)` (e.g. where you set `length` and `code`) Opposite you want to use a `posedge CLK` where you work with your STATE.
7. Use one clock and one clock only. Do not use CLK **and** CLOCK_50. Use either one or the other.
8. Take care of your vector sizes. This `8'd25000000` is wrong as you can no fit 25000000 in 8 bits.

Your usage of `halfsecflag` is excellent! I have see many times where people think they can use `always @(halfsecflag)` which is a recipe for disaster!

Below you find a small piece of your code which I have re-written.

- All assignments are non-blocking `<=`
- `halfsecflag` is essential to operate the code only every half a second, so I put that by itself in a separate `if` at the top. I would use that throughout the code.
- All register are reset, both `COUNT2` and `dashflag`.
- `dashflag` was set to 1 but never set back to 0. I fixed that.
- I specified the vector sizes. It makes the code "Lint proof".

Here is it:

```
always @(posedge CLOCK_50 or posedge RESET)
begin
   if (RESET == 1'b1)
   begin 
      COUNT2 <= 2'd00;
      dashflag <= 1'b0;
   end // reset
   else if (halfsecflag) // or  if (halfsecflag==1'b1)
   begin     
      if (COUNT2==2'd2))
      begin
         COUNT2 <= 2'd0;
         dashflag <=1'b1;
      end
      else
      begin
         COUNT2 <= COUNT2+2'd1;
         dashflag <=1'b0;
      end
   end // clocked 
end // always
```

Start fixing the rest of your code the same way. Write a test-bench, simulate and trace on a waveform display where things go wrong.

Comment: Thank you for looking at it. Couple things to note. The CLK signal is actually a button that you press to display a morse letter. (The letter that is to be displayed is chosen with 3 switches 000 being A, 001 being B and so on. Other than that, your advice was pretty solid.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would build the finite state machine to produce the output. That machine would have some stages, like reading the input, mapping it to a sequence of morse code element, shifting out the elements to output buffer, waiting for conditions to move to the next morse element. You will need some timer that would produce one morse time unit intervals, and depending on the FSM stage you will wait one, three or seven time units. The FSM will spin in the waiting stage, it doesn't "magically" sleeps in some fpga-produced delay, there's no such things.