# I'm writing some verilog code and I keep getting error code "Can't resolve multiple constant drivers"?

Tags: verilog, state-machine

I'm trying to implement a morse code display on my FPGA. I've written a lot of code but I keep getting the same error message. Before I get into that though, please take a look at the assignment. To be clear, I'm not asking for someone to do the assignment for me. I just need help debugging my code.

"Part IV
In this part of the exercise you are to implement a Morse-code encoder using an FSM. The Morse code uses patterns of short and long pulses to represent a message. Each letter is represented as a sequence of dots (a short
pulse), and dashes (a long pulse). For example, the first eight letters of the alphabet have the following representation:

A • —

B — • • •

C — • — •

D — • •

E •

F • • — •

G — — •

H • • • •

Design and implement a Morse-code encoder circuit using an FSM. Your circuit should take as input one of
the first eight letters of the alphabet and display the Morse code for it on a red LED. Use switches SW2−0 and
pushbuttons KEY1−0 as inputs. When a user presses KEY1, the circuit should display the Morse code for a letter
specified by SW2−0 (000 for A, 001 for B, etc.), using 0.5-second pulses to represent dots, and 1.5-second pulses
to represent dashes. Pushbutton KEY0 should function as an asynchronous reset.

Here is the code I have written:

```
module part4 (SELECT, button, CLOCK_50, RESET, led);
input [2:0]SELECT;
input RESET, button, CLOCK_50;
output reg led=0;
reg [26:0] COUNT=0; //register that keeps track of count
reg [1:0] COUNT2=0; //keeps track of half seconds
reg halfsecflag=0; //goes high every time half second passes
reg dashflag=0; // goes high every time 1 and half second passes
reg [3:0] code; //1 is dot and 0 is dash. There are 4 total
reg [1:0] c3=2'b00; //keeps track of the index we are on in the code.
reg [2:0] STATE; //register to keep track of states in the state machine
wire done=0; //a flag that goes up when one morse pulse is done.
reg ending=0; //another flag that goes up when a whole morse letter has 
flashed
reg [1:0] length; //This is the length of the morse letter. It varies from 1 
to 4
wire i; // if i is 1, then the state machine goes to "dot". if 0 "dash"

assign i = code[c3];
assign done= (halfsecflag)&&(~ending)&&~led;

parameter START= 3'b000, DOT= 3'b001, DASH= 3'b010, DELAY= 3'b011, IDLE= 
3'b100;

parameter A= 3'b000, B=3'b001, C=3'b010, D=3'b011, E=3'b100, F=3'b101, 
G=3'b110, H=3'b111;


always @(posedge CLOCK_50 or posedge RESET) //making counter
begin
if (RESET == 1)
COUNT <= 0;
else if (COUNT==25'd25000000)
begin
COUNT <= 0;
halfsecflag <= 1;
end
else
begin
COUNT <= COUNT+1;
halfsecflag <=0;
end
end

always @(posedge CLOCK_50 or posedge RESET)
begin
if (RESET == 1)
begin
COUNT2 <= 2'd00;
dashflag<=1'b0;
end
else if ((COUNT2==2)&&(halfsecflag))
begin
COUNT2 <= 2'd0;
dashflag<=1'b1;
end
else if ((halfsecflag)&&(COUNT2!=2))
begin
COUNT2<= COUNT2+2'd1;
dashflag<=1'b0;
end
end


always @(posedge button or RESET) //asynchronous reset
begin
STATE<=IDLE;
end


always@(*) begin //State machine
case (STATE)

START: begin
led <= 1;
if (i) STATE <= DOT;
else STATE <= DASH;
end

DOT: begin
if (halfsecflag && ~ending) STATE <= DELAY;
else if (ending) STATE<= IDLE;
else STATE<=DOT;
end

DASH: begin
if ((dashflag)&& (~ending))
STATE <= DELAY;
else if (ending)
STATE <= IDLE;
else STATE <= DASH;
end

DELAY: begin
led <= 0;
if ((halfsecflag)&&(ending))
STATE<=IDLE;
else if ((halfsecflag)&&(~ending))
STATE<=START;
else STATE <= DELAY;
end

IDLE: begin
c3<=2'b00;
if (button) STATE<=START;
STATE<=IDLE;
end

default: STATE <= IDLE;

endcase
end


always @(posedge button)
begin
case (SELECT)
A: length<=2'b01;
B: length<=2'b11;
C: length<=2'b11;
D: length<=2'b10;
E: length<=2'b00;
F: length<=2'b11;
G: length<=2'b10;
H: length<=2'b11;
default: length<=2'bxx;
endcase
end

always @(posedge button)
begin
case (SELECT)
A: code<= 4'b0001;
B: code<= 4'b1110;
C: code<= 4'b1010;
D: code<= 4'b0110;
E: code<= 4'b0001;
F: code<= 4'b1011;
G: code<= 4'b0100;
H: code<= 4'b1111;
default: code<=4'bxxxx;
endcase
end

always @(*)
begin 
if (c3==length) 
begin
c3=2'b00; ending<=1;
end
else if (done)
c3= c3+2'b01;
end 

endmodule
```

The error code I keep getting is Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "c3[1]" at part4.v(68)

Also in green above this error code, it says inferred latch a few different times. This doesn't seem good! Can you take a look at my code and see if you can figure out why I'm getting this error message?

Update: This is not a duplicate of my previous question. Before I was asking for tips on how to create a delay using verilog. In this question I was asking for help debugging my code. The error message I got was not making sense to me. I looked at the other answers on stack exchange regarding that error code but none of them made sense to me.

Comment: If you type "multiple constant drivers" in the search bar you get 189 answers.

Comment: Hold on. @Oldfart wrote you a [very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54503115/6411653) to your last question. First suggestion in there was to properly indent your code. Otherwise it's basically unreadable. I've even gone through the trouble of indenting your last question for you, once that edit is approved. The second suggestion in Oldfart's answer was to look up "multiple constant drivers for net". Don't post the same question multiple times, if you have an update to your previous question, edit it.

Comment: you write reg `c3` multiple times in different always blocks, also you initialize it.  This causes your message. Get rid of initialization ( which gets ignored in real synthesis in any case) and make sure that you modify `c3` in a single always block only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to program a delay in Verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491819/how-to-program-a-delay-in-verilog)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a couple of (very) basic principles - you can't code hardware without them. Note that I'm using VHDL terminology here ('signal'/'process'/etc), but the idea is exactly the same in Verilog, if a little harder to find the right words.

1. You can only drive a signal from a single process (if you're synthesising, anyway), or you get multiple drivers. Look at c3 - where is it driven? You're driving it from 2 combinatorial always blocks. The same is true of STATE.
2. In a combinatorial process, if you read one of your output (driven) signals before you assign to it (drive it), you're inferring *memory*. This is where your inferred latches are coming from. Think about it - a process "wakes up" when something it is sensitive to changes/fires. If it then reads the value of a signal that it itself drives, this must mean that the signal has to be recorded somewhere in order for it have a current value; it must know what value it had when the process last completed. This is what memory means. You do this for both STATE and c3 (`if(c3==length)` must *read* c3, `case STATE` must *read* state).

You fix (1) by recoding so that all signals are driven from only one 'owner' process.

Fixing (2) is more difficult. In a combinatorial process (`alway @*`) make sure you either give all outputs default values first, or make sure that you never read anything before you've written it, so that there's no confusion about whether memory is inferred. Your combinatorial process to derive STATE is wrong. You read STATE, and then write it. You should have 2 signals: current state, and next state. You should read the current state, and create the next one.

You've got other problems, but you need to fix those 2 first.